# Updating a UILabel Through A Function....Is There Something I'm Missing?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I asked a question similar to this one earlier but this question is more about the general language and fundamentals of Swift. In the code below, shouldn't this function technically work and change the label text? I've been running it for a while now and every time it fails. I've made sure that all of my outlets are linked properly as well. Sorry if the answer is obvious, I'm new to Swift.

```
func changeLabel() {
    DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: {
        self.testText.text = "YES"
    })
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let city:String? = nil
    if city == nil {
        changeLabel()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is always called from the main thread (unless a programmer mistakenly does otherwise - and that's a whole other problem).

So there is no point to using `DispatchQueue.main.sync` to update the label. In fact, it's bad in this case. Calling `DispatchQueue.main.sync` when already on the main queue will cause the app's user interface to hang until the app is killed.

You have two choices:

1. Remove the use of `DispatchQueue.main.sync` since it's not needed in the code you posted.
2. Change `sync` to `async`. This fixes the problem with the app user interface hanging and it also allows you call the `changeLabel` method from any queue and work properly.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been searching about this for the past few days for a project I'm working on and I just couldn't seem to find the right answer. Thankfully, this solved it all.

Answer (score -2):

Use this instead:

```
func changeLabel() {
     DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: {
     print("teste")
     DispatchQueue.main.sync{
        self.testText.text = "YES"
    }})
```

Thanks